# if checkbox is checked and option is selected remove disabled class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the condition with jQuery but don't get success. I want if checkbox is checked and select option is selected then remove disabled class from the anchor button.

This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#limitation").change(function() {
    if ($("#child-limit").is(':checked') == "true" && $("#piller").val()) {
      $("#limitation").removeClass("disabled");
    } 
  else if ($("#child-limit-1").is(':checked') == "true" && $("#piller-2").val()) && $('input[name=gender]:checked').val() == "yes") {
       $("#limitation").removeClass("disabled");
 }
  else {
      $("#limitation").addClass("disabled");
    }
  });
  $("#limitation").change();
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background: #cdc8c7;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-limit" id="child-limit" />
<select id="piller" name="firstpillers" class="select">
      <option value="" class="placeholder" selected disabled>Make choice</option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1 </option>
      <option value="2">2</option>                                 
    </select>

<a href="#" id="limitation" class="btn disabled">Volgende stap</a>
```

This code works fine when i check only select condition like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    if ($("#piller").val()) {
      $("#limitation").removeClass("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#limitation").addClass("disabled");
    }
  });
  $("select").change();
});
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `$("#limitation").change(function(){` shouldn't it be on the `select` instead? `$("select").change(function(){` also this one too, `$("#limitation").change();` should work fine after you change those https://jsfiddle.net/0dc3kwmf/ also remove the `== "true"` it will return rue or false already

Comment: You don't need the  `== "true"` after the `is(':checked')`, if you want to keep it, don't wrap true in quotes as you are testing for a string rather than a bool

Comment: This is a typo. It should be `#piller` instead of `#limitation` which is actually an anchor tag. Please vote to close this.

Comment: @palaѕн that is a typo or copy and paste error but there is something else that breaks this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned the handlers to the wrong element

Additionally you test a boolean for equality with a string `.is(':checked') == "true"` which is wrong (and unnecessary to test)

I might code it like this

```js
function enableLink() { // test value is selected AND checkbox is checked
  var ok = $("#piller").val() != "" &&  $("#child-limit").is(':checked');
  $("#limitation").toggleClass("disabled",!ok); // disable if false
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#piller").on("change",enableLink).change(); // run on change and run change on load
  $("#child-limit").on("click",enableLink); // run on click
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background: #cdc8c7;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-limit" id="child-limit" />
<select id="piller" name="firstpillers" class="select">
      <option value="" class="placeholder" selected disabled>Make choice</option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1 </option>
      <option value="2">2</option>                                 
    </select>

<a href="#" id="limitation" class="btn disabled">Volgende stap</a>
```

To add more conditions do

```
var ok = ($("#piller").val()   != "" && $("#child-limit").is(':checked')) ||
         ($("#piller-2").val() != "" && $("#child-limit-1").is(':checked') &&
          $('input[name=gender]:checked').val() == "yes"));
```

Comment: It would good if you explained why the code did not work before so the OP will know next time

Comment: Sorry, I meant why OP's code did not work before but it is also good that you commented on your code

Comment: Yes but that's just a comment, your answer is more important, anyway it's your answer, the OP by code, looks like a beginner dev, and I think it would be good for him/her to know what went wrong. The typo is a small thing, but that `== "true"` that is a logic error

Comment: Hmm - I always read complete questions and their comments. My answer was also meant to show how much more compact the code could be without repeating and simpler to debug

Comment: Oh yes for sure, I completely agree with that

Comment: i have updated my js code, i hope you understand my required condition what i want. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Check for condition.. == true in place of =='true'

Comment: No need to check a boolean for == true